# Drag an element(H2 eg.) to div, but contenteditable is invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I use (Jquery2.0) draggable to drag an element(for example h2) to a div, h2 has the attribute `contenteditable=true`, but when i dragged,
only two operation can make the h2 editable:

1) I refresh the page,

2) or I click the left bottom of div eage, but not h2 itself.

how can I edit h2 by clicking the h2 itself, instead refresh or click other places.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: i can't abstract my problem since involved too much.  another info, my project is the same as bootstrap visualization [link](http://www.bootcss.com/p/layoutit/ ), try to drag a layout and head bar, the same question would repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. i drag the element to nested div, but i don't set the attr handle when i use the draggable. I add the handle and works fine.